# Why my code doesn't deciding correctly from list elements that they are prime numbers or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I want to decide that the numbers are primes or not, and if they are then append to a new list (called primes in my code).I have a nums=[], random-filled list.

```
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    for j in range(1,len(nums)-1):
        if(nums[i]%j==0):
            counter+=1
    if(counter==2):
        primes.append(nums[i])
```

Comment: you never reset counter, so as soon as you find two numbers that have 0 remainders, you'll never ever detect another prime again. plus... if you find a number that has no remainder, why bother counting farther?

Comment: You're alright. It is answered that why I receive only one number or nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a cleaner way with an upper bound on the divisor.

```
primes = []
for num in nums:
    for divisor in range(2, int(num ** .5) + 1):
        if num % divisor == 0:
            break
    else:
        primes.append(num)
```